# Downscale images to corresponding device

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

I've run into some issues when trying to display some wallpapers in a single scrolling grid view. In my grid view I have 6 images I want the users to be able to scroll through.

The problem I am having is that I am getting a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" crash on specific devices when loading the images. The app doesn't crash on my own phone(Sony Xperia T, 800x1280), but crashes on my friends phone(Samsung GS2, 800 x 480). The resolutions of the images I am trying to load are 1280x800(Size varies from 200-350kb). I think I know how to solve this issue but need help on the solution of how to accomplish it.

Is there any way to downscale the images to the corresponding resolution of the device that the user is using to save memory?

Here's the code I am using, hopefully someone could give me some guidance.

AdapterView class:

```
package com.question;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AdapterViewADV extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.Image1,
        R.drawable.Image2,
        R.drawable.Image3,
        R.drawable.Image4,
        R.drawable.Image5,
        R.drawable.Image6

};


public AdapterViewADV(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(NO_SELECTION, NO_SELECTION));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = null;
    if(convertView == null){
       imageView  = new ImageView(mContext);imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(NO_SELECTION, NO_SELECTION));
       convertView = imageView;
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Change your `getView` like this hope this will help. You can also search for using `ViewHolders` in `ListView` `Adapters`.

Comment: When using this code, it prompts me to initialize imageview, should I initialize it?

Comment: The app crashed when I use the code you gave me, the error states "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" then under that "Java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: post the whole stack trace

Comment: For some odd reason the code is now working after cleaning the project. Will this now help with my issue I am getting?

Comment: You can accept the answer if you find it good, your issue was you where creating new instance of the imagevie when ever get view is getting called. List view reuse the items so first check if the getView is called with a valid view or not